# Why transactions remain queued in txpool of geth client?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

Transactions remain stacked in geth client's txpool. Below is my node's current status,

> txpool.status
>   {
>     pending: 3836,
>     queued: 459
>   }>
>   Is it the count of my local node only?
>   How can I resolve it?

Comment: probably because the gas price is too low, what is the gas price you are using? you solve this by rewriting the transaction with increased the gas price. you have to use the same `nonce` when you rewrite a pending transaction